# How to filter data out of tabulated stdout stream in Bash?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, awk

Here's what output looks like, basically:

```
?       RESTRequestParamObj.cpp
?       plugins/dupfields2/_DupFields.cpp
?       plugins/dupfields2/_DupFields.h
```

I need to get the filenames from second column and pass them to `rm`. There's AWK script that goes like `awk '{print $2}'` but I was wondering if there's another solution.

Comment: As a curiosity, `grep -o '[ ][^ ]*$'` will keep one space before each file name, but if you have filenames without spaces, that might be acceptable for passing to `rm`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have spaces between the `?` and the filename then:

```
cut -c9-
```

If they're tabs then:

```
cut -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

Placed your output in file

```
$> cat ./text 
?       RESTRequestParamObj.cpp
?       plugins/dupfields2/_DupFields.cpp
?       plugins/dupfields2/_DupFields.h
```

Edit it with sed

```
$> cat ./text | sed -r -e 's/(\?[\ \t]*)(.*)/\2/g'
RESTRequestParamObj.cpp
plugins/dupfields2/_DupFields.cpp
plugins/dupfields2/_DupFields.h
```

Sed in here is matching 2 parts of line -

1. ? with tabs or spaces
2. Other characters until the end f the line

And then it changes whole line only with second part.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 echo "?       RESTRequestParamObj.cpp" | sed -e 's/^\S\+/rm /' | sh
```

or using GNU sed

```
 echo "?       RESTRequestParamObj.cpp"| sed -r 's/^\S+/rm /e'
```

Answer (score 0):

**bash** only solution, assuming your output comes from stdin:

```
while read line; do echo ${line##* }; done
```

Comment: ... and assuming you don't have file names with spaces. To zap just the first character, try `${line#?}`. (That's s wildcard, not a literal question mark; add a backslash in front to only remove question marks.)

Answer (score 0):

use cut/perl instead

```
cut -f2 -t'\t'|xargs rm -rf

<your output>|perl -ne '@cols = split /\t/; print $cols[1]'|xargs rm -rf
```